# Can a PySpark Kernel(JupyterHub) run in yarn-client mode?

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, jupyterhub, spark-ec2

My Current Setup:

- Spark EC2 Cluster with HDFS and YARN
- JuputerHub(0.7.0)
- PySpark Kernel with python27

The very simple code that I am using for this question:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2])
rdd.collect()
```

The PySpark kernel that **works as expected** in Spark standalone has the following environment variable in the kernel json file:

```
"PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master spark://<spark_master>:7077 pyspark-shell"
```

However, when I try to run in yarn-client mode it is getting stuck forever, while the log output from the JupyerHub logs is:

```
16/12/12 16:45:21 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/12/12 16:45:36 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/12/12 16:45:51 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/12/12 16:46:06 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

As described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) I have added the **HADOOP_CONF_DIR** env. variable to point to the directory where the Hadoop configurations are, and changed **PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS** `--master` property to "**yarn-client**". Also i can confirm that there are no other jobs running during this and that the workers are correctly registered.

I am under the impression that it is possible to configure a JupyterHub Notebook with a PySpark kernel to run with YARN as [other people have done it](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/438), if this indeed is the case what I am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have your pyspark works in yarn mode you'll have to do some additional configurations:

1. Configure yarn for remote yarn connection by copying the
   `hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-<version>.jar` of your yarn cluster in the `<local hadoop directory>/hadoop-<version>/share/hadoop/yarn/` of your jupyter instance (You need a local hadoop)
2. Copy the `hive-site.xml` of your cluster in the `<local spark directory>/spark-<version>/conf/`
3. Copy the `yarn-site.xml` of your cluster in the `<local hadoop directory>/hadoop-<version>/hadoop-<version>/etc/hadoop/`
4. Set environment variables:

   - `export HADOOP_HOME=<local hadoop directory>/hadoop-<version>`
   - `export SPARK_HOME=<local spark directory>/spark-<version>`
   - `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=<local hadoop directory>/hadoop-<version>/etc/hadoop`
   - `export YARN_CONF_DIR=<local hadoop directory>/hadoop-<version>/etc/hadoop`
5. Now, you can create your kernel in file `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json`

   ```json
    {
       "display_name": "pySpark (Spark 2.1.0)",
        "language": "python",
        "argv": [
         "/opt/conda/envs/python35/bin/python",
         "-m",
         "ipykernel",
         "-f",
         "{connection_file}"
        ],
        "env": {
         "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/opt/conda/envs/python35/bin/python",
         "SPARK_HOME": "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0",
         "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/",
         "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/shell.py",
         "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master yarn pyspark-shell"
        }
       }
   ```
6. Relaunch your jupyterhub, you should see pyspark. Root user doesn't usually have yarn permission because of uid=1. You should connect to jupyterhub with another user

Answer (score 0):

I hope [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073549/how-can-i-run-pyspark-interactively-in-jupyter-using-yarn-client-mode/50126060#50126060) can help you.

I config the url by simply passing a parameter:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("yarn-clinet", "First App")
```