# How can I run Pyspark interactively in Jupyter using YARN-client mode?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

Now I have succeeded in running Pyspark in Jupyter in local mode by the second method as mentioned in this [blog](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f).
Here is the code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "First App")
```

I want to run it interactively in YARN-client mode,how can I do it?
Let's go futher,how to run in different modes,e.g.standalone mode and YARN-cluster mode.

Comment: What is your Yarn-client URL? Also, you will need to use `SparkConf()`. Please edit your question adding more details about the configurations. Docs : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The source code says that the constructure method of `SparkContext` accepts either key-value pairs or a `SparkConf()` object, so my method of configuring is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Accrding to the [Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) :

> Master URLs accepts `yarn` parameter based on the HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR variable

So I can simply use:

`sc = SparkContext("yarn-client", "First App")`